# Dynamically Sized UILabel Followed Directly by UIButton

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton, uilabel

How can I position a UIButton right at the end of a dynamic UILabel?

Here is a screenshot of what I'm trying to achieve:

[image: example]

Comment: Is all of the label's text on 1 line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you using Autolayout? If so, add horizontal spacing constraint and baseline alignment constraint between the label and the button. Make sure also that numbers of lines of the label is 0.

Comment: How does this work if the sometimes the label is half a line followed directly (on the same line) by the button, but sometimes the line is 1.5 lines to be followed directly by the same button.

Comment: Horizontal spacing mean that no matter what the width of the label, it will always "stick" to the button by a constant number you define.

Comment: The problem is if I set the number of lines of the label to 0 it creates as many lines as necessary based on the size of the label in the storyboard. Which is fine if the text was going to be one line long every time, but it won't be. How can I make the label as long as necessary and as many lines as necessary to fit the text, but wherever it ends immediately followed by the button. Regardless of wether it ends on the first line or the fifth line?

Comment: I don't understand the problem please attach screenshot of desired result.

Comment: I added an image showing what I am trying to achieve.

Comment: @user1828081 ok, now it's much clearer; however, unfortunately to you, this makes your question much harder :) I don't know a way to get the width of the last line in a dynamic label - if we did have that number we could set the horizontal constraint between the label and the button to be the difference between the width of the label and the width of the last line in the label.

Comment: Ok thanks for your help I may consider modifying how I display it in order to make it simpler.  I may be able to align the buttons so they always fall in a similar place.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
[your_label sizeToFit];
CGRect rect = your_button.frame;
rect.origin.x = CGRectGetMaxX(your_label.frame);
your_button.frame = rect;
```

Comment: When I use this the button disappears.

Comment: What frames do label and button have before and after this code?

Answer (score 0):

I'd override `-[UIView layoutSubviews]` and do what you want there. Once you do that, the code will look something like Avt's answer. If you want the label to have multiple lines, but a constrained width, you may want to try something like

```
CGSize labelSize = [yourLabel sizeThatFits:CGSizeMake(someWidth, 9999)];
```

and use that to set the label's frame.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the button to appear at the bottom of the UILabel, use constrains.
 [image]